# Spring WebClient does not decode application/octet-stream into File object

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Hi I am using OpenAPI Generator Maven Plugin to generate some Java Client code (using Spring WebClient library). One of the endpoints of my spec. returns binary content, like:

```
"schema": {
  "type": "string",
  "format": "binary"
}
```

The generated code uses `java.io.File` as the return type for that, like:

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<File>> downloadWithHttpInfo(String filename) throws WebClientResponseException {
    ParameterizedTypeReference<File> localVarReturnType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<File>() {};
    return downloadRequestCreation(filename).toEntity(localVarReturnType);
}
```

When calling this generated method, the response code was 200 (i.e. OK from the server side), but I got the following error in my client code:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException:
    Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported for bodyType=java.io.File
```

This came from the `toEntity()` method, which is part of the Spring WebClient code instead of my code.

Is there a way to workaround this? A: Instruct OpenAPI Generator Maven Plugin not to use `java.io.File` type but use `Resource` type? B: Somehow make WebClient able to decode application/octet-stream into `java.io.File`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution: add the following options to the OpenAPI Generator Maven Plugin then generate the code again, which would replace `File` to `Resource`

```
<generatorName>java</generatorName>
<library>webclient</library>
<typeMappings>string+binary=Resource</typeMappings>
<importMappings>Resource=org.springframework.core.io.Resource</importMappings>
```

The above is saying when the return type is `string` and the format is `binary`, map it to `Resource` and for `Resource` import it as `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`. There you go.

Comment: This worked for me, then I used `InputStream responseStream = response.getBody().getInputStream()` to get the responseStream. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, but using Gradle instead of Maven.
Here is the syntax for doing the same in Gradle:

```
task generateClientSources(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask) {
    generatorName = 'java'
    // other configs ..
    configOptions = [
            // other configs ..
            library : 'webclient'
    ]
    typeMappings = [
            File : 'Resource'
    ]
    importMappings = [
            File : 'org.springframework.core.io.Resource'
    ]
}
```